# Google sheets - find last value column index and get value from another row in that index + 1

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have the following sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GcC47i7193Hjt0QbTQ5OT_2SZQjPO_4wKmKKMwy_hQE/edit?usp=sharing

I need to get the date (from row 1) for each of the products (col a) corresponding with the col one after the **last value in each row**.

EG

For product `A` it would be `1/2/2021`
For product `B` it would be `1/3/2021`

Answer (score 2):

To raise the limitation of the `VLOOKUP` [formula](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66352073/1527780) by [JPV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3889423/jpv),

> Assuming there's only one "D" per row

you can use the following for any number of `x`'s in any number of rows

```
={"Product","Date";
         QUERY(INDEX(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(B2:D6="x", A2:A6&"_"&B1:D1,)),"_")), 
            "select Col1, max(Col2) where Col2 is not null 
             group by Col1 label max(Col2) '' ",0)}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there's only one "D" per row, in B8 try

```
=filter($B$1:$D$1, filter($B$1:$D$6, $A$1:$A$6=$A8)="D")
```

and fill down.

For a single formula (array output) try in B8

```
=INDEX(VLOOKUP(A8:A12, SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(B2:D6="D", A2:A6&"_"&B1:D1,)), "_"), 2, 0))
```

See if that helps?